# How to make my react native app appear in the share list on android

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, android-sharing

I'm trying to make my react native app appear in the share apps list, for example from youtube. How do I do this exactly?
If someone could please guide me on what I have to add to my java files on android, that'd be great, as I have close to no experience with java.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try this package [https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

<s>You can use [Deep Linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) by react-navigation for your application. Related article [here](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e).</s>

Please refer to my comment instead.

Comment: Hi. From what I've read, there needs to be some modification to the Mainactivity.java file for my app too appear as an option to share from other apps, for example sharing a video from youtube. I could not get that working, as with my vague knowledge of java, the article was very cryptic about where to add that method. Could someone please expand on this? For your reference, the link of the article is https://www.bennettnotes.com/react-native-android-receive-data-from-share-intent/